# In Wagtail v2 API, how do I filter by a foreign key's string (provided by the __str__ method)

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, filtering, wagtail

So I have a blog type of website where I'm trying to use the API to get a list of articles filtered by their topic. Here is the relevant portion of my ArticleDetailPage() class with the API field:

```
class ArticleDetailPage(Page):
    """Article detail page."""

    ...

    topic = models.ForeignKey('articles.ArticleTopic', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    ...

    api_fields = [
            ...
            APIField('topic', serializer=serializers.StringRelatedField(many=False)),
            ...
    ]
```

And here's my ArticleTopic() class:

```
@register_snippet
class ArticleTopic(models.Model):
    """
    Article topics that resides in Snippets.
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    slug = AutoSlugField(
        populate_from='name',
        editable=True,
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='slug',
        allow_unicode=True,
        help_text='A slug to identify articles by this topic.'
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('slug')
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Article Topic'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Article Topics'
        ordering = ['name']                             # Alphabetial ordering

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So far so good, when I take a look at the API list of posts, instead of showing the topic attribute as its ID and other data, it's represented as its string representation (i.e. a topic like space or comets). However, when I try to filter the API by appending:

```
&topic=space
```

to the HTML, I get an error saying:

```
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'space'.
```

Instead of using the StringRelatedField(many=False) serializer, I switched to

```
APIField('topic', serializer=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True))
```

So each topic is represented only as its ID and when I perform the same filtering above but using the ID instead of the string name, it works!

Ideally, I'd want to just filter using the string name instead of the ID for other purposes in my project. Anyone have any experience on this or would like to chime in?

Comment: I'm also looking for this answer. It's a shame no one answered.